# Can't see pages on page listing after Wordpress update

Tags: wordpress

After upgrading wordpress, I can't see my pages on the pages listing. As you can see from the screenshot below, I have 24 pages, but it just says record not found.

[image: all]

But if I click on Published, I can see my published pages.

[image: published]

I've never used WordPress before, and prior to updating, I've backed up everything. I don't want to rollback entirely, as this is the only problem that surfaced.

Following guidelines online, I've tried deactivating all my plugins, but the problem is still there, so its not plugins. I've also tried updating the current theme (which broke my site!), but that didn't fix it either. Any other things I should be looking into?

Answer (score -1):

Please check every post to see whether it is set to "Published". If so, please also check the database to see whether the "posts" table has been filled out correctly with all posts. The "post_status" column must have the status "publish". In addition, the "post_type" column must contain the value "page".

From my personal experience, it can be after a WordPress update that not all pages are displayed immediately, but it can be fixed again after another WordPress update.